# How to deselect a file from (disabled) file input in cypress?

Tags: typescript, cypress

I have a disabled file input (`<input type="file">`) and I have selected a file with `selectFile('filepath', { force: true })`. This works fine.

But now **I want to deselect the file**:

I tried `.clear({ force: true })` and `.selectFile(null, { force: true })`, but they don't work.

Comment: Why do you want to deselect the file, can the user do so? Would you not be better following the actions a user would take?

Comment: Or have you turned of test isolation?

Comment: @icecub no. it does not work for file inputs

Comment: @Gino.Diamantopoulos Yes, the user can click to upload and then click cancel to deselect file. Since we have some special logic when a file is deselected I need to test it. Why should I turn off test isolation?